# Do animals suffer in agony or pain the same way like homo sapiens suffer?

Tags: behaviour, instinct

When an animal suffer in agony or pain, do they feel it the same way as homo sapiens or human beings?

I saw a documentary where it showed that while the child cattle were being slaughtered mother cattle were crying. Is that really crying or is it just secretion of tears from tear glands like it always happens?

Do they have the sense to feel suffering like we suffer? If it is true then is the sense of suffering prevalent among all the animals equivalently?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZG0MgCSZ2g

Comment: @AlexReynolds Thank you. That answers my question.